# What is the correct way to build complex queries in web2py's DAL?

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

I am using web2py's [DAL](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer) and trying to do the equivalent of this MySQL query.

```
SELECT header.tag, detail.site
FROM header 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN detail ON header.id= detail.header
WHERE header.tag IN ('abc', 'def', 'xyz')
```

I presumed that the DAL equivalent was as follows, but this code is giving me a cross product.

```
tags = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
query = (db.header.tag.belongs(tags) & db.header.id==db.detail.header)
raw_data = db(query).select(
    db.header.tag,
    db.detail.site,
)

SELECT header.tag, detail.site FROM header, detail;
```

If I omit the [`belongs`](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#belongs) clause from my query, all works fine.

```
query = (db.header.id==db.detail.header)
raw_data = db(query).select(
    db.header.tag,
    db.detail.site,
)

SELECT header.tag, detail.site FROM header, detail WHERE (header.id = detail.header);
```

I am using this version: `2.12.3-stable+timestamp.2015.08.18.19.14.07`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `left` parameter on your `select` method. Check the documentation for Left Outer Join here: http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Left-outer-join

Answer (score 1):

```
query = db.header.tag.belongs(['abc', 'def', 'xyz'])
db(query).select(db.header.tag, db.detail.site,
                 left=db.detail.on(db.header.id == db.detail.header))
```

For me, see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Left-outer-join.

Comment: Yeah, i missed giving an example of usage on the answer :P